# Comparing partitions of a finite set

Tags: reference-request, permutations

Suppose you have a set $S$ of cardinality $n$, and you generate $k$ partitions on this set such that each partition breaks the master set $S$ into roughly even groups of size $m$. I say roughly in the case that $m$ does not divide $N$ evenly, and the remainder is placed in it's own group. (For simplicity of a solution, I'm willing to restrict the problem to even partitions of $S$)

What measures or statistics are available / recommended for (a) comparing the 'similarity' or dis-'similarity' of two partitions, and more generally (b) the 'similarity' or dis-'similarity' of the set of partitions?

While the context of this problem is not particularly important for the ask, I'm trying to permute a data-set as a proxy for simulation. My aim is to credit (or discredit) the value of the random permutations of my data set against how repetitive or similar the observed partitions happened to be.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is to look at the distance between $\pi_1, \pi_2$ on the Haase diagram of the poset where $\pi_1 \leq \pi_2$ when $\pi_1$ is a refinement of $\pi_2$.   e.g., look at the minimum number of edges between $\pi_1, \pi_2$ on [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Set_partitions_4%3B_Hasse%3B_circles.svg) diagram from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

Comment: Another option would be to look at the size of the greatest common refinement $\wedge S$ of the set of partitions $S$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of comparing partitions $P$ and $Q$ of the same finite set $X$ appears to be important in cluster analysis. Several similarity measures are known to be useful:

- the Mirkin metric
- the variation of information
- the van-Dongen-metric
- the classification error metric

The definitions of all of them can be found in the article

https://www.stat.washington.edu/mmp/Papers/icml05-compare-axioms.pdf

by Marina Meila.